# Is there a hotkey in Android Studio's commit dialog to show changes without touching the mouse?

Tags: android, git, android-studio, version-control, keyboard-shortcuts

I commit often in Android Studio and I always check the changes first. I can press Ctrl-K to open the commit dialog and there I should be able to use F7 to go through the changes.

The problem is by default the commit message editor is selected and there F7 does not work for some reason.

Is there a hotkey to focus the changes pane, so F7 works?  I can do it with the mouse, but I commit frequently, so I'd like to do all these from the keyboard without using the mouse.

Comment: What do you mean use "F7 to go through the changes", do you mean check the diff of the changed file(s)? And F7 is not the default keyboard shortcut, which item does the F7 keymap with?

Comment: Yes, I meant go through the diffs. F7 is the Next Difference hotkey for me on windows. It is the default hotkey for me and apparently for others too, e.g.: https://medium.com/@akbarsha03/version-control-system-using-git-on-android-studio-a632eb00bea9

Answer (score 1):

The direct answer is no.

In commit changes window, it focus on commit Message by default, and it can not be changed. So hotkey can not be used since no files is focused in the commit changes window.

The work around is **view diff of the un-committed files before opening the commit changes window**:

First add two keyboard shortcuts in keymap:

Such as <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd> for compare with Same Repository Verison, and <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd> for Show Local Changes.

[image]
[image]

Before commit changes, you can check the local changes by <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd>, and check the diff of a file by <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd>.

[image]

After view the diff the the un-committed files, then you can open commit changes window to commit directly.

Comment: Thanks, I'll try this. The real question is why F7, which is a default hotkey for next difference in the commit dialog, does not work in the message field. It does not interfere with the message text, so it should work there and then the user experience would be seamless. I guess it's a bug you can't use the F7 hotkey while editing the commit message.

Comment: F7 hotkey only works when a file comparison window is opened. Such as in the last screen shot, only when `1.sh` file comparison window is open, then F7 hotkey works. Since the commit window is focus on commit message, not changed files, and there is no file comparison window open, so F7 can not work. Only when you focus a changed file -> click Enter key -> file comparison window is open -> then use F7 to check next diff.

Comment: The commit dialog already shows the diffs at the bottom, I don't have to open any new window. I only want to scroll through the diffs which F7 could do from anywhere in the commit dialog, since the diffs are already there at the bottom pane. F7 not working globally in the commit dialog is clearly a bug, because F7 does not have any other function in the dialog, so pressing it anywhere in the dialog should do the same as pressing it when the diff pane is focused.

Comment: Yes, find it. And It seems even by Tab button, the diff window can not be focused neither, only if by clicking mouse. You can feedback the issue by Help -> submit feedback in android studio. It should be improved.